# escape # using iis rewrite FileMapProvider

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

using iis rewrite is great, but how does the module interpret a hashsign in the url.

This works:

```
/fromurl;/anotherurl
```

But this does not:

```
/fromurl#;/anotherurl
```

How do I "output excape" a hashsignin the from url.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the hashmark isn't sent to the server, so the rewrite module can't react to it.

This means that /fromurl and /fromurl# would result in the same url (as seen by the server)

Comment: This is correct. The hashmark is reserved to anchors, so the hashmark is never sent to the server side